# How can i push a TableView on clicking a button and initialize the TableViewCell with NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios5, nsmutablearray

Can anyone please  help me about how to push a table view on clicking a button.
I want to load the messages from NSMutableArray to the table view cells and NSMutableArray is loaded with the data parsed from a URL..

```
-(IBAction)readMessages:(id)sender
{
    // i want to push the tableview when clicking the button in relation with this method
    // WHAT MUST I DO HERE?

   }
```

Instead of asking a new question i liked to edit this one, since the matter is in the same aspect..
I now can create the tableview programatically, but i cant initialize its cells with the data i get from Json array. Here is my code:

```
NSString *str1=[@"?username=" stringByAppendingString:userNameField.text];
        NSString *str2=[@"&password=" stringByAppendingString:passwordField.text];
        NSString *str3=[str1 stringByAppendingString:str2];
        NSString *str4 =[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];


        NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[str4 stringByAppendingString:[@"/ipad/login.php" stringByAppendingString:str3]]];
        //get the url to jsondata
        NSData *jSonData=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

        if (jSonData!=nil) {
            NSError *error=nil;
            id result=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jSonData options:
                       NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
            if (error==nil) {
                NSDictionary *mess=[result objectForKey:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messContent=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"message"];
                NSDictionary *messID=[mess valueForKeyPath:@"ID"];
                NSString*key1=[ result objectForKey:@"key" ];                
                NSString *s1=[@"http://" stringByAppendingString:serverField.text];
                NSString *s2=[s1 stringByAppendingString:@"/ipad/button.php"];
                NSURL *url2=[NSURL URLWithString:[s2 stringByAppendingString:[@"?key=" stringByAppendingString:key1]]];

                NSData *data2=[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2];
                id result2=[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data2 options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

                 mesID = [NSMutableArray array];//saving meesage ID s to NSMutableArray
                 content = [NSMutableArray array];    
               // i logged here and it saves  the data, now i want to display my data in table view

                for (NSDictionary *data in mess) {
                    [mesID addObject:[data objectForKey:@"ID"]];
                    [content addObject:[data objectForKey:@"message"]];        
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:messID forKey:@"message"];
                    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:messContent forKey:@"messContent"];

                    //messID will be saved as the Title of the cells and messContent will be displayed as the text area of that cell, opening in a new view
```

And this is the output, i want to set the titles of cells as ID and their content as text:

```
  2012-01-17 16:26:59.873 ipad_Teslim[940:f803] MessID: (
        1,
        3
    )
    2012-01-17 16:26:59.875 ipad_Teslim[940:f803] Content: (
        asdf,
        "this is a test"
    )
```

As i have mentioned in my code too, messID will be saved as the Title of the cells and messContent will be displayed as the text area of that cell, opening in a new view.. How can i do it now? Please Help me, there are a lot of tutorials there, i looked a lot too but couldn't break this problem.

Comment: by the way, i use the code above in a different method of my class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Q1: U no need to add a navigation to return back to ur main page.
When ever u use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
```

by defaults it will creates back navigation in the next view to push return back.

in case it doesn't created yet, Try the following code in next view:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //To set the back buttin on leftside of Navigation bar
    UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(backclick:)] autorelease];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;

}

- (IBAction)backclick:(id)sender //first declrared in .h file
{
    // To goback to the previous view
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
-(IBAction)readMessages:(id)sender {

    SecondView *secondView =[[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:secondView animated:YES];    

  }
```

SecondView is your UIViewController subclass which hold a UITableView.

Answer (score 1):

If u have a navigation control and if u want to pushed by navigation try the following:

```
-(IBAction)readMessages:(id)sender {
 NextView *next = [[NextView alloc]initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:next animated:YES];
        [next release];
}
```

if u dont have a navigation control and if u want to just display the next view, try the following:

```
-(IBAction)readMessages:(id)sender {

    NextView *next =[[NextView alloc] initWithNibName:@"NextView" bundle:nil];

    [self presentModalViewController:next animated:YES]; 
           [next release];
  }
```

if u are having sub view in the same class try the following:

```
-(IBAction)readMessages:(id)sender {

      [self.view addsubview nextView];
      }
```

Comment: sorry, i'm a little un-experienced in Objective C. I dont have any xib files, i want to create the view programatically. Do i need to create a xib file to use these codes?

Comment: ask for any help from 10am to 6pm (indian timings)..
select Tick any one of the above answers it's better to u to get quick responce by by increase the accepatance rate

Comment: Thanks @Prasad, im in Turkey in fact i cant imagine what time it is now at your place. I think it is about 8-9 p.m.:)

Comment: @prasad give your number dude it will helps us to get from you in any time

Answer (score 1):

Yes U can,
try this to create xib programitically in viewDidload:

```
UIView *view1 = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10,300,460)];
    view1.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [self.view addSubview:view1];
```

But better to create by using
following path in xcode menu:

File-> New -> NewFile -> UIViewControllerSubClass -> Next -> Next -> Create

Or simply Drag & drop an view from ur Interface Builder

Comment: You can edit your existing answer instead of creating a new one.

Comment: Thnks @vin, but i used this way since   ilhan çetin was new user..
for readability to him im writing like this.

thans once again

Comment: Yes u too improve ur skills as well as others by helping others theoug ur answers..
welcome

Comment: I created a UITableView (not UIView) with this your code in my methood. Now i have two matters: One, how can i add a navigation controller to turn back to my main page? Two: how can i initialize this tableviewcells with my JSON array(i have allready parsed JSON and initialized in an NSMutableArray)? My question may come boring but really i couldn solve..

Answer (score 1):

Q2: U can initialize ur tableView cells with JSONArray:

```
 (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [JSONarray count]; //***********
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


       cell.textLabel.text = [JSONarray objectAtIndexIndexPath.row]; //***********
}
```

Comment: but i parse data in a diffrent method, when i try this it brings something strange in NSLog(), and nothing in cells. I haven't tried your this sollution, i will turn you back. Thanks